# Software Installation Issue With Shutter

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I have recently been trying to install Shutter and I get This error when I type `sudo apt-get install shutter`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-wnck-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-gconf-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libxml-simple-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libwww-mechanize-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libwww-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: perlmagick
           Depends: libgtk2-imageview-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnet-dbus-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libproc-processtable-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libjson-xs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnet-dropbox-api-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libgtk2-appindicator-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I came about this solution because for this game, scrabble AI, a standalone scrabble game, I needed sudo apt install libgnome2-canvas-perl, which did not work.

however, this page to install shutter using a ppa got it for me and the game now works.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt update

sudo apt update shutter
```

shutter does open up after installing some plugin updates.
I then removed the ppa from software sources, just to be cautious.

edit:  oops forgot the most important thing (for me) the scrabble game
https://github.com/apikler/ScrabbleAI

unzip, run 
    perl scrabble.pl from where you put it.